# Reading complex, base-64 encoded XML files into a spark dataframe/

Tags: xml, apache-spark, base64

I have thoroughly researched this problem and not come up with any answers, however I am new to Spark and may have missed something.

I have been given a set of files which are base-64 encoded XMLs which I have been asked to convert into dataframes so that some analysis can be performed. I can decode them:

```
import base64
decoded = lines.map(lambda l: base64.b64decode(l).decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
```

And now I have a PipelinedRDD object with 15 lines, each of which is a string representation of a very complex nested XML file. The actual file is most likely commercially sensitive, but to give you an idea:

```
<MessageBody>
    <MessageProperties>
        <SomeProperty>text</SomeProperty>
        <SomeOtherProperty>
            <Code>text</Code>
            <Name>text</Name>
        </SomeOtherProperty>
        <DateTime dateType='Departure'>a date</DateTime>
        <DateTIme dateType='Arrival'>another date</DateTime>
```

The actual XML text is as I said much larger. There are many nested properties, and many tags have the same name (such as DateTime) with additional information given in the tag.

I am aware of the spark-xml library, but have no idea how to make it read a string instead of an actual XML file, or if it could handle an XML this complex.

I know Python's ElementTree library can create a tree from a string, but have no idea how to convert this tree into a dataframe other than writing some recursive function which takes all the tag names (like DateTime) and additional information (like dateType='Arrival') and assigns them to column names, and the text inside (like 'another date') to values, but I have been told this is too inefficient and that there must be a way to simply read the XML string to a dataframe.

If it helps, I do have .xsd files for the XMLs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.